# Determine host CPU from list of devices obtained in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I am calling `clGetDeviceIDs` by passing an array of `cl_device_id` and getting all possible devices. Now from this list I want to remove the device which is actually the host CPU?
Is there any fool proof way to do this?
Because there might be 2 exactly identical CPU installed then `cl_device_info` might not be helpful in differentiating the 2 CPU?

Comment: What do you consider to be the "host CPU"?  The CPU on which your host code is executing *right now*?  Unless specified otherwise, SMP systems can and will reschedule your process to execute on another CPU at will.

Comment: Brian is right: The OS schedules processes across all CPU cores, and OpenCL CPU drivers also use all CPU cores. Therefore *any* CPU device you get from OpenCL is by definition the CPU you are running on. If you don't want to run on it, then only run on GPU and ACCELERATOR devices.

Comment: But if I do not queue the host CPU cl_device_id for the kernel execution then OpenCL should not run anything on it. My understanding was that OpenCL takes control over which devices to run the kernel on. Why would the OS force the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCL 1.1 and later, you can check if the device and the host have a unified memory subsystem by using `CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY` with [`clGetDeviceInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html).

Comment: Looks like that works in OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 only;   `CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY` option of [clGetDeviceInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) is deprecated in OpenCL 2.0. See [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.0.pdf) §F.3; I don't see a reason for deprecation, nor an obvious replacement. Further confusion, it still appears on [the refcard](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/OpenCL-2.0-refcard.pdf) without qualification. FYI @Cool_Coder also.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will give you wanted control over client devices.

```
//See how many platforms do we have
int num_platforms;
int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms)
if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

//Collect list of platforms
cl_platform_id *platforms = (cl_platform_id*)calloc(num_platforms, sizeof(cl_platform_id));
ret = clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);
if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

//Collecting list of Devices for every platform
for(int i=0; i<num_platforms; i++){
    int num_CPUs, num_GPUs;
    cl_device_id *CPUs, *GPUs;

    //Get number of CPUs & GPUs on client machine
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, NULL, &num_CPUs);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &num_GPUs);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

    //Allocate memory & collect actual information
    CPUs = (cl_device_id*)calloc(num_CPUs, sizeof(cl_device_id);
    GPUs = (cl_device_id*)calloc(num_GPUs, sizeof(cl_device_id);

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,num_CPUs, CPUs, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,num_GPUs, GPUs, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS) {fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", ret);}

    //Do whatever you want with Devices
    ....

    free(CPUs);
    free(GPUs);
}

free(platforms);
```

Comment: from the CPUs array, if I remove the cl_device_id corresponding to the host CPU then OpenCL should not run any kernel on it, right?

Comment: Just don't use corresponding cl_device_id, no need in deleting

Comment: ok but how do I determine which cl_device_id in the CPUs array is the host CPU?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. BTW, for what reason this may be needed?

Comment: Firstly the GUI thread is running on host CPU and I dont want to cause any flicker. Secondarily I want to manage other cores than the GUI core by myself for doing some other tasks.

Comment: Not sure if OpenCL is intended for things like this. Just pick up GPU & start calculating, let the drivers do the rest.