# Check OpenCL version compatibilty correctly?

Tags: opencl

My application is OpenCL 1.1 compatiable and I want to check whether each of the device has drivers for that version. There are 2 ways for this:

1. clGetDeviceInfo() ->CL_DEVICE_VERSION
2. clGetPlatformInfo() ->CL_PLATFORM_VERSION

I have following doubts:

- I do not understand why method 1 is provided as method 2 seems the
  correct way to me?
- Is it possible that the version given by the    platform will not
  match with the version given by a device from the    same platform?
- What is clGetDeviceInfo::CL_DRIVER_VERSION for?
- From all these options which one should I use to check if a device
  can run my OpenCL 1.1 code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some features in OpenCL that have hardware requirements. This means that even if a particular vendor's OpenCL implementation (the **platform**) supports an OpenCL version, the **device** might not. So, it is entirely possible for the versions returned from the `CL_DEVICE_VERSION` and `CL_PLATFORM_VERSION` queries to differ.

This will probably start to happen more frequently when OpenCL 2.0 implementations start appearing, as there is plenty of hardware on the market that doesn't have the necessary support for OpenCL 2.0 features. Imagine a system that has two devices from *Vendor X*: a new *Device A* that can run OpenCL 2.0, and a much older *Device B* that can't. In this instance, the **platform version** may be OpenCL 2.0, but the **device version** could be OpenCL 2.0 for *Device A* and OpenCL 1.2 for *Device B*.

The `CL_DRIVER_VERSION` is for getting a vendor specific version number for the implementation. This  number could using any version numbering system that the vendor uses to keep track of different software releases, and is completely independent from OpenCL version numbers (although some vendors may well include the OpenCL version here too).

So, in order to be sure that both the device and platform support your required OpenCL version, you should just need to check `CL_DEVICE_VERSION`.

Comment: I understand that the version supported by platform may not be supported by the device, but is the vice versa possible?

Comment: I think technically it is possible, but probably unlikely. I believe that a lot of the latest GPUs are capable of OpenCL 2.0 for example, so it would be feasible that CL_DEVICE_VERSION could return 2.0, even if the implementation itself hadn't been updated to allow access to the 2.0 features. This scenario may never actually happen in practice, but in theory I believe that CL_PLATFORM_VERSION and CL_DEVICE_VERSION are completely independent.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It helped a lot! I have another question the answer to which I am not fully satisfied with. Can you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229856/determine-host-cpu-from-list-of-devices-obtained-in-opencl

Comment: Right. It is possible for the device version to be less than the platform version, but I don't think it is possible for it to be the other way around.

Comment: On re-reading the spec, this appears to be true - my previous comment is incorrect and I've amended my answer accordingly.